# replacing default radio with images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve two things here.
1: I am trying to show content on clicking the radio button
2: I am trying to replace the default radio button with images

I could have completely eliminated the idea of radio and just do a click show with images but the ultimate task is to capture the users input and send is as an email. I am excluding that part in this question. My solution works fine in chrome but in IE 8 I am not able to show content. in IE 9 it works

Here is my current attempt:

JavaScript:

```
  $(function(){

  var options = $('#options').find('input');
    options.click(function(){
      var id = "opt" + $(this).val();
      $(".optDivs").hide();
      $("#" + id).show();

    });

  var selections = $('#selections').find('input');

    selections.click(function(){
      var id = "opt" + $(this).val();
      $(".slctDivs").hide();
      $("#" + id).show();

    });

  });
```

Html:

```
<html><head>    
<style>
    #one{
        position:absolute;
        left:-99999999;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="options">
        <div class="opt1">
            <input type="radio" name="primary" id="one" value="1"> 
            <label for="one"><img width="50px" src="http://gfxlovers.com/smilies/imgs/smiling/smiling025_2.gif"></label>
        </div>
      <div class="opt2"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="2"> Option 1</div>
      <div class="opt3"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="3"> Option 1</div>
    </div>

    <div id="opt1" class="optDivs" style="display:none;">content option 1</div>
    <div id="opt2" class="optDivs" style="display:none;">content option 2</div>
    <div id="opt3" class="optDivs" style="display:none;">content option 3</div>


    <div id="selections">
      <div class="opt4"><input type="radio" name="secondary" value="4"> Option 2</div>
      <div class="opt5"><input type="radio" name="secondary" value="5"> Option 2</div>
      <div class="opt6"><input type="radio" name="secondary" value="6"> Option 2</div>
    </div>

    <div id="opt4" class="slctDivs" style="display:none;">content option 5</div>
    <div id="opt5" class="slctDivs" style="display:none;">content option 6</div>
    <div id="opt6" class="slctDivs" style="display:none;">content option 7</div>



<div id="chrome_hitahintpanel" style="opacity: 0; display: none;"><input id="chrome_hitahintinput" type="text"></div><div id="chrome_hintswindow"></div><div id="chrome_linksearchpanel" style="opacity: 0; display: none;"><input id="chrome_linksearchinput" type="text"></div></body></html>
```

You can see it hosted and working [here](http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/Kemail/testForRadio.html).

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you do a fiddle instead?

Comment: yes let me do that too

Comment: this is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/44dfv/

Comment: @benjamin--thanks man for doing that. I made the fiddle too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hide your radio elements with CSS and show images instead. You should then capture the images in jquery (or similar) to check if one of the images is being clicked. If it is: Add a checked-attribute to the corresponding radio-element.

Comment: Can you please explain how would soum accomplish that? Preferably with code?

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/KbTCx/
For reasons of simplicity I took colored divs instead of images, but you get the grasp ;)

Comment: @hurrtz- thanks. I get the concept. I can combine this with what I am trying to do.